# Constructor in JavaScript/React is required?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This code is requiring a constructor. 
I'm not understanding the need to have a constructor to use the 'this'
(Eu não estou entendendo a necessidade de ter um construtor para usar o 'this')

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View} from 'react-native';


class Botao extends Component{

this.styles = StyleSheet.create({}); // requiring a constructor

render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>Clique</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
  }
```

can I do it this way without using it?

```
class Botao extends Component{

render(){
    return(
       <TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text style={this.styles.texto}>Clique</Text>
            </View>
       </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
    texto:{
        fontSize: 60
    }
}); 

}
```

Comment: Yes, the second way is how to do it. Declaring `styles` like that makes it a class property which is accessed from elsewhere in the class with `this`

Answer (score 6):

You actually have two options here...

1) Use the class constructor:

```
class Botao extends Component{

  constructor(){
   this.styles = StyleSheet.create({}); // requiring a constructor
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>Clique</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

2) Declare it directly as a class property (without `this`):

```
class Botao extends Component{

  styles = StyleSheet.create({});

  render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <View>
                <Text>Clique</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

In both cases, you would access `styles` from elsewhere in your class using `this.styles`

If you're writing a React component, you usually don't need to use the constructor method. As it says in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t need to implement a constructor for your React component.

Comment: what is the role of the constructor in the first case?

Comment: Note that the second option uses syntax which is not yet a part of standard javascript, and thus requires babel's plugin-proposal-class-properties to use. React applications commonly use this plugin. Writing the code the second way gets transpiled into the first way.

Comment: without the constructor, 'this' does not assume the global scope?

Comment: @wesif I've updated my answer with some more info - in short, it serves no useful purpose. `this` has global scope in both cases, but if you choose to attach your `styles` property in the constructor, you have to use `this` in order to attach it to the containing class.

Comment: @Will Jenkins, I understand perfectly, I just do not understand the relation of this to the constructor.

Comment: Before construction, there is no instance, and so `this` has no meaning. Does that help?